# Else statement not being able to start a statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

When I put in a else statement after my if statement I get an error saying that else can not start a statement.

```
using System;

namespace If
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to calculator");

            Console.WriteLine("Chose an operator +, -, *, / ");
            string oper = Console.ReadLine();

            if (oper == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to add to another number:");
                int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number add to " + num1);
                int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int num3 = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + num3);
            }
            else
            {
                if (oper == "-") ;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to subtract from another number");
                    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
                    Console.WriteLine("enter a number to subtract from " + num1);
                    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
                    int num3 = num1 - num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer " + num3);
                }
                else
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Drop `;` in `if (oper == "-") ;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
    if (oper == "-") ; // ";" is the culprit
    {
      ...
    }
    else
      ...
```

fragment. Drop `;` it should be

```
    if (oper == "-")
    {
      ...
    }
    else
      ...
```

Your current code means:

```
// if oper == "-" do nothing - ;
if (oper == "-") ;
```

then `{..}` block comes which has *no connection* with if

```
{
  ...
}
```

finally, you have *orphan* `else` which cause compile time error.

**Edit:** try avoiding *nested* `if`, but use `else if`

```
if (oper == "+") {
  ...
}
else if (oper == "-") {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```